# Suppress the -h/--help argument in argparse

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

When you create an parser with argparse there is always a default help menu that looks something along the lines of:

```
usage: program [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

For example if I did the following:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-t", "--test", help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
parser.parse_args()
```

And suppressed one of the arguments help messages I would get:

```
usage: program [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

How can I suppress the `-h/--help` flag as well?

Comment: help=argparse.SUPPRESS just suppresses the help for that particular argument

Comment: do you still want to use -h?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the optional keyword argument `add_help=False` when you initialize your `ArgumentParser` object

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#add-help